# How can "have different taste" be used?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

I hear this phrase often when people have different likes. But can I say something like this?

> People have different taste in animals, some people like cats more while some people like dogs more.

I used the phrase in similar way to

> have different taste in music.

I thought this sounds funny because it gives the nuance that people like dogs (or cats) for their taste.

I would like to know how I can apply this phrase to other sentences.

Comment: The noun _taste_ has more than one meaning, as you apparently know. English speakers can almost always determine from context which meaning is intended; no-one would be likely to misunderstand your sentence. It's hard to understand what you mean by _"I would like to know how I can apply this phrase to other sentences."_ Can you add an example of this kind of sentence to your question to help us understand? (You can use the [edit] link under your question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your phrases

> People have different **tastes** in animals
>   have different **tastes** in music.

you want to use the *plural* since each person will *have their own* ***taste***.

In your usage of "***tastes***" is synonymous with "***likes***".

> His **taste** runs to long legged blondes.

When you hear

> people have different tastes in animals

is can be the start of a bad joke

> What's your taste in animals?
>   *I like mine medium rare.*